# how to change the default background color of EidtText error message

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, message

I want to change the background color of the error message to white and text color to red. 
I could change text color using html formatted text. As it does not support css styling, i am unable to change the background color of the error message.

[image: image for reference]

Comment: You should probably add the code you're using.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can change the background using the default popup, you would have to create your own popup.

But a better solution might be to use TextInputLayout to wrap your EditText, and then set the error on the TextInputLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hint"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Then use

```
mTextInputLayout.setError("your error string");
```